# Travel Salesforce CRM Showcase

Tags: salesforce, crm, apex, b2b

to improve my knowledge and skills with Salesforce, I plan to build up an Salesforce Org (CRM, Apex, flows, triggers ...) for Hyper Travel Company. :).

What is Hyper Travel Company: This is a hypothetical company created base on my experience in the travel industry. All features will be as real in order to demonstrate how Salesforce can meet the demand of real world business. It will be tough, so I need you suggestions from you about CRM features, business logics, real travel company's operations, etc..

About me: I have two Salesforce Admin Certificates and Salesforce Platform Developer I Certificate, experience with data entry in Salesforce, experience with relational databases and C#.

**And here is my brainstorm about Hyper Travel Company so far (All features are real)**

It is a B2B travel destination company. That means they provide services for the destination of Vietnam to other agencies around the world. Their products and services mainly are:

**Provide Vietnam tours:**

- Each tour can include multiple cities such as Hanoi, Hue, Ho Chi Minh. Each tour can include multiple service such as tour guides, transportations, accommodation, dining service.
- There will be template tours that international agencies can choose from, like three-day North East Vietnam, 5-day Hanoi-Hue-Ho Chi Minh, Hanoi-Ho Chi Minh, etc..
- Template tours are just sample tours. Actually trips are derived from tours with modifications such as additional attractions, additional services.
- Price are vary and based on not just the number of guests. For example three single adults may need three single rooms, while a couple with a kid just need a room with extra bed.
- There maybe many kind of unpredicted expenses would occur during a trip.

**Provide hotel rooms only:**

- As the name suggested, hotel only is the accommodation service only, with price usually more expensive then hotel room in a tour package.
- Each hotel may have multiple room types such as Superior, Deluxe, also may be Economical and Royal, all up to them.  Each type may include single room and double room. Double room type may or may not allow extra bed. A couple with a kid can have the option to use extra bed or not (it's all about the cost)
- It's common that a hotel usually set up their room prices different in different time periods of a year called "seasons". Those seasons are vary from hotel to hotel, base on how busy the hotel are during the year. The prices differences may be included in their price sheet, but also can be in form of surcharge, either provided as a money amount or a percentage of increase.

As you see, it's really complicated and I will need many help. First step I will build up the database structure with standard and custom objects and fields. I will post the link here when there is something to show :). Thank for reading.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a personal blog. Do you have any actual question? Code samples you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some first progresses.
Being a developer, I thought of tours as products, because in other programs or websites we just put them all in a table and display it somewhere. But within Salesforce we need a correct definition of "product" because it can affect opportunities and reporting.

Turn out tours are not products, but they are set of products. True products are hotel rooms, transportation services, guide services, etc.. All of them will be put into product object, categorized by Type field with values of "Accommodation, Transportation, Dining, Tour Attractions, Other".

Hotel properties are added as additional product fields such as Star Rating, Has Swimming Pool, Restaurant, Pet Allowed, Smoking Free, etc..

A account lookup field is added to the product object: As this is B2B, all products are related to a business (account). Small products and services will relate to Hyper Travel(us).

Three new objects added:

- Tour: Template tours which will be used to copy over when we create opportunities
- Tour Itinerary: Tour schedule with look up field to Tour. Records are supposed like Day 1, Day 2 ...
- Itinerary Product: Look up fields to Tour Itinerary and Product. Will be used for copy over to opportunity products. Here is the
  [Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJLbx.png)